# How to remove multiple spaces and line breaks from the library after building?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

In one new project, I found that `eslint` and `prettier` do something like this in some places:

```
<button
  v-for="(item, index) in items"
  :key="index"
  class="
    block
    w-full
    bg-white
```

That is, the classes are "built" in a column.

I understand that this behavior can be turned off, but...

In the generated code, these classes look like this:

```js
{key:r,staticClass:"\n      block\n      w-full\n      bg-white\n
```

The library is built by `vue-cli-service`. Is there any way (more or less out of the box) to clean this up?

And do you think this is rubbish, because in the user's browser in the source code of the page, these classes will also be arranged in a column?

Comment: I personally like this formatting. It increases readability especially when compared to a huge single line string. Also, I believe others like this formatting otherwise `prettier` wouldn't be so popular or it would have different default formatting rules.

Comment: @bassxzero In terms of source code and work with it, I agree with you. I'm only confused by this abundance of spaces after building the library.

Comment: Checkout packages like `uglify`. They might be able to help you remove spaces in your final build.